# Get a full solution for a conda environment

Tags: conda

Let's say I have a simple conda environment

```
dependencies:
  - python
```

How do I turn this into a fully specified environment?  I want to run the Solve step of conda and save the result, but not run any of the other steps yet.

I would prefer to avoid actually having to download and extract packages to do this.

I would also love to be able to do this from within Python without shelling out, but that's just an additional request.

Answer (score 1):

You can do,

```
conda create -n testenv python --dry-run
```

to get the output and parse it or get the output as json using

```
conda create -n testenv python --dry-run --json
```

Comment: Thanks.  In my case I am given an environment file.  If possible, I would love to find a solution that takes an environment file as an input.